# org-brain-visualize alignment issue on Mac OS

Tags: org-mode, align

I am having trouble getting the Picture art in `org-brain-visualize` to align properly. I have tried this with several versions of Emacs, both run as a Mac app and from the Terminal:

- Org-brain version 0.5
- Org mode version 9.1.9
- GNU Emacs macports binaries 25.2.1
- GNU Emacs 26.1 (both the Home brew and Railwaycats editions)
- Savannah emacs compiled from scratch

I have tried this from a Retina display and non-retina, run from the Mac desktop and Terminal. But same issue.

When I run `org-brain-visualize` I am supposed to see this:

[image]

but instead, I get this:
[image]

Here is my `init.el` file:

```
;;; Add path to src directory
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp")

;;; Set default org directory
(setq default-directory "~/org/")

;;; Configure org-brain
(require 'org-brain)
(setq org-brain-path "~/org/brain")
(setq org-id-track-globally t)
(setq org-id-locations-file "~/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations")
(setq org-brain-visualize-default-choices 'all)
(setq org-brain-title-max-length 50)
```

The issue appears to persist any time I add more than one Parent for a Child node.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like tabs/spaces issue. Are any of the characters used to display the diagrams tabs rather than spaces?

Comment: @wvxvw I have not looked at the source code, so not sure (would not necessarily be able to interpret it anyway). But it sounds like a good guess! I did notice that the issue is less pronounced in the fork by Sodel-the-Vociferous. I believe he mentioned something about spaces v. tabs in one of his commits...